# What is the difference between assigning a pointer to variable address and explicitly to memory address?

Tags: c++, pointers

See the following pieces of code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int *p=&a;
    *(p+1)=6;
    cout<<*(p+1);
}
```

The code above does not work. However, the following piece of code, which assigns to an explicit memory address, does work:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int *p=(int *)0x28fefc;
    *(p+1)=6;
    cout<<*(p+1);

}
```

Why would one of these methods work and not the other?
I have used a memory address of my computer in the second one.this address may not work in some other machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: process returns a negative value and terminates immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are both undefined behavior. You are trying to modify memory that you did not allocate. The second is even less safe, because you are assuming `a` is going to be allocated to that address every time, which is absolutely not a safe assumption.

Comment: @user3553836 undefined behaviour means that everything is possible but with out any guarantee. Because is "working" on your pc doesn't mean it would work somewhere else.

Comment: It isn't "working", it is undefined behavior. That means that the standard does not specify what should happen. The compiler may let you do that, it may throw an exception, it may crash your computer, or it may do nothing.

Comment: thanx i got it!!! that means for using any memory i have to allocate it first with the help of variable declaration etc?